# Integrating over large masked arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate a large array of y values over a simple 1d interpolation and then integrate the result.

Here is the code so far:

`wavelengths` is an array of shape [nredshifts, nwavelengths]

`fluxes` is an array of shape [nmodels, nwavelengths]

```
from scipy.integrate import simps

transmission = scipy_interpolant(wavelengths)[..., np.newaxis]  # from a previously defined scipy.interpolate.interp1d class
propagated = transmission * fluxes.T
wavelengths = wavelengths[..., np.newaxis]
wavelengths = np.repeat(wavelengths, mult.shape[-1], axis=-1)
top = simps(propagated, wavelengths, axis=1)
bottom = simps(transmission, wavelengths, axis=1)

result = top / bottom  # shape of [nredshifts, nwavelengths]
```

This code currently works. However, there is a flaw: there is extra amount arising from the integration. Its better if I explain using these pictures:

Integration as normal will find the area under this curve:
[image: Integration as normal will find the area under this curve]

But I need it to find the area under this curve:
[image]

So I am encountering this 1d problem over a 3d array (integrating over `axis=1`) where not all the x (wavelength) values are the same!

I could do that with 1d arrays fairly easily: just remove the offending sections: `x[(x > 3) & (x < 7)]` for instance.  However, I can't do this with three dimensional arrays because their wavelengths are all different. I have attempted setting the offending entries to `0` or `np.nan` but then `simps` just returns `nan`s. I've tried using masked arrays in the hope that scipy is smart and knows what I want but it seems to ignore the masks!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Only `np.ma` functions and methods treat masked arrays correctly.  For use in other code use `ma.compress` to remove the masked values or `ma.filled` to replace them.